# Jquery runs fine in console but not when I load the page

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of jquery code for an image-gallery that I have in a js file along with a few other functions. When I load the gallery by clicking on the link, the images come up but the effect doesn't work. However when I paste the concerned code in the chrome console and press enter, it works like a charm. Is there some kind of conflict that I have overlooked ?
My jquery code is below (although i dont think there's a problem in it as it works good when I have the code run independently on a separate webpage or through console):

```
$(document).ready(function() { //perform actions when DOM is ready
  var z = 0; //for setting the initial z-index's
  var inAnimation = false; //flag for testing if we are in a animation

  $('#pictures img').each(function() { //set the initial z-index's
    z++; //at the end we have the highest z-index value stored in the z variable
    $(this).css('z-index', z); //apply increased z-index to <img>
  });

  function swapFirstLast(isFirst) {
    if(inAnimation) return false; //if already swapping pictures just return
    else inAnimation = true; //set the flag that we process a image

    var processZindex, direction, newZindex, inDeCrease; //change for previous or next image

    if(isFirst) { processZindex = z; direction = '-'; newZindex = 1; inDeCrease = 1; }     //set variables for "next" action
    else { processZindex = 1; direction = ''; newZindex = z; inDeCrease = -1; } //set variables for "previous" action

    $('#pictures img').each(function() { //process each image
      if($(this).css('z-index') == processZindex) { //if its the image we need to process
        $(this).animate({ 'top' : direction + $(this).height() + 'px' }, 'slow', function() { //animate the img above/under the gallery (assuming all pictures are equal height)
          $(this).css('z-index', newZindex) //set new z-index
            .animate({ 'top' : '0' }, 'slow', function() { //animate the image back to its original position
              inAnimation = false; //reset the flag
            });
        });
      } else { //not the image we need to process, only in/de-crease z-index
        $(this).animate({ 'top' : '0' }, 'slow', function() { //make sure to wait swapping the z-index when image is above/under the gallery
          $(this).css('z-index', parseInt($(this).css('z-index')) + inDeCrease); //in/de-crease the z-index by one
        });
      }
    });

    return false; //don't follow the clicked link
  }

  $('#next a').click(function() {
    return swapFirstLast(true); //swap first image to last position
  });

  $('#prev a').click(function() {
    return swapFirstLast(false); //swap last image to first position
  });
});
```

**Update 1** :
There's another function for hashchange in the script, it goes like this :

```
$(function(){
  $(window).hashchange( function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if((hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4))&&(hash!='')){
        var toLoad = hash+'.php #content';
        $('#content').load(toLoad);
    }                                           
});
$('#nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').load(toLoad);

});

});
  })
```

And it seemed that this function is called everytime there's hashchange in the URL, which could be the reason why my gallery-function is not called. I have tried putting the gallery function inside hashchange function, but it doesnt work. I have a feeling that there's a conflict here, coz the alerts in my gallery function are not triggering.

**Update 2:** I read in jquery-documentation for load function that if the load function is executed like this   $('#b').load('article.html #target');  then the script blocks in the document being loaded are not executed. Could that be the problem, how do I overcome this?

Comment: how are you loading it that's not working?  can you provide code?

Comment: Is jquery being referenced before this code?

Comment: @Matt The image gallery is a module in the website, and every other effect is working except this one. I have the above code in a common js file and I am loading the whole file in the beginning like this :  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>  Again, every other function in the script works. Also, when I paste the above code in the chrome-console as-is and press enter, the effect starts working.

Comment: @pilotcam Yes, the line <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  lies above the one that calls scripts.js

Comment: What happens when you bring up the javascript console in Chrome, then reload the page.  Any errors?

Comment: @pilotcam .. there's no difference. I do a ctrl-F5 after bringing up console, and there are no errors and effect doesn't work.